# Equivalent definitions of the second-order/Lorentz cone

Tags: convex-cone

I have come across two different definitions of the second-order/Lorentz cone. The first is the standard form where $t$ is a scalar and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
$$
\mathcal{C}_1 = \bigg\{ \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{y} \\ t\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}: t \ge \lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert_2\bigg\}
$$

The second definition is from this [paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2003/file/1843e35d41ccf6e63273495ba42df3c1-Paper.pdf). Here the cone is defined for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
$$
\mathcal{C}_2 = \big\{\mathbf{x} : \mathbf{x}^{\sf T} \mathbf{1} \ge \sqrt{n}\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_2 \big\}
$$

Are $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis of the first cone is in the direction $(0,0,\ldots,0,1)$, while the axis of the second cone is in the direction $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$. There is also some scaling difference in the sharpness of the cone (the factor $\sqrt{n}$).

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer. I'm going to try and "rotate" $\mathcal{C}_2$ to be in the canonical form.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{C}_3 = \{\mathbf{x}: \mathbf{x}^{\sf T}\mathbf{1} \ge \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_2\}$ the appropriate "rotated" version of $\mathcal{C}_1$?

Comment: @SrinivasEswar Actually, now that I think about it, there is no scaling difference. The condition is $x^\top u \ge \|x\|_2$ where $u$ is a unit vector. In the first cone, $u=(0,\ldots,0,1)$ and in the second cone $u=(1,\ldots,1)/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Isn't that slightly different then since the variable $t$ in $\mathcal{C}_1$ should appear in the norm on the RHS as well?

Comment: @SrinivasEswar If $t$ is the last element of a vector $x$ ,then $t=x^\top (0,\ldots, 0, 1)$.

Comment: Yes but the RHS is no longer $\lVert x \rVert$ but rather $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \ldots + x_{n-1}^2}$, right?

Comment: @SrinivasEswar Ah, you are correct. So they are not quite the same thing. Apologies for my mistakes.

Comment: So does the rotated cone looks correct?